# Django ajax search responds with 404 status

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to make a simple search using ajax in my django application.

I have the following model:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And here's my javascript:

```
function search_success(data){
    $('#search_results').hmtl(data);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_ingredient").on('change', function () {
        update_unities();
    });

    $('#search_ing').on('keyup', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/search/',
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search_ing').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: search_success,
        });
    });
});
```

In my urls.py, I added the following:

```
path('ajax/search', views.search_ingredients, name='search_ingredients')
```

And in my view, I defined the following function:

```
def search_ingredients(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    ingredients = Ingredient.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)
    return render('recipe/search_ingredient.html', {'ingredients' : ingredients})
```

I'm getting a 404 error on my request, can someone help me out?

EDIT: Here's my folder structure.

```
.
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── migrations
│   ├── omitted
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── recipe.css
├── templates
│   └── recipe
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── recipe_add_ingredient.html
│       ├── recipe_detail.html
│       ├── recipe_edit.html
│       ├── recipe_list.html
│       └── search_ingredient.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: You omitted the trailing slash in your `path` line.

Comment: @Selcuk you mean just doing path('ajax/search/', ...) ? Do you have any other idea? I added it and still getting the same error, I will edit my question with the folder structure.

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion. I suggest you to enable DEBUG and visit the URL (`http://localhost/ajax/search/`) manually to see what is wrong.

Comment: Your terminal should show you the exact URL you are requesting. Very likely, you are just a folder up/down from where you should be.

Comment: @WayBehind Yea, I noticed I had two things wrong (updated on question) and when I access the url that's being requested I get a TemplateDoesNotExist and it points to this line in my views: return render('recipe/search_ingredients.html', {'ingredients' : ingredients}). You have any idea or anything that could help?

Comment: I don't know much about ajax and javascript so I used this https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it is pretty easy to use

Comment: @RedCricket that's for django 1.9, I'm on django 2 :/ thanks for the help though

Comment: Sorry. The docs must be out of date.  If you look here https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects#compatibility you'll see it supports Django 2

Comment: You should return json data instead of rendering template. and parse json response to render in HTML. Also try with `/` removed from `url: '/ajax/search`. You can use **Network** tab of Browser Developer Tool to see the request and response you are getting. If you are getting 404 error. You can see what is the cause for the error in **Network** tab.

Answer (score 0):

fist of all:

change this:

```
path('ajax/search', views.search_ingredients, name='search_ingredients')
```

by this:

```
path('ajax/search/', views.search_ingredients, name='search_ingredients')
```

check the trailing slash at the end of the expression:

in the return statement of your view function, it should start with the request:

```
return render(request, 'recipe/search_ingredient.html', {'ingredients' : ingredients})
```

I hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ensarman but unfortunately it didn't solve it. I'm still getting the same 404 error. Any other idea? I can share my github where I have the whole code if you wanna take a look.